# How to add additional Google calendar via CalDAV?

Tags: google-calendar, caldav

I want to add an additional Google calendar via CalDAV.

I know that the URL for the personal calendar (the one with your name) looks like this: https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/USERNAME@gmail.com/events, but I don't know how to get the URL for additional calendars created by myself.

What is the URL for additional calendars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calendar ID needs to be used instead of the e-mail address. This ID can be found in the settings and sharing options in the section integrate calendar.

So the URL looks like this: https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/CALENDAR_ID/events.